# Gatsby : Error running "gatsby --help" after installing node, Homebrew, and npm

Tags: gatsby

After successfully installing Node (v13.5.0), npm (v6.13.4), Homebrew (v2.2.1), and Gatsby-cli globally, I run into this error:

```
$ gatsby --help
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/code-frame'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/prepare-stack-trace.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/errors.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/create-cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/prepare-stack-trace.js:13:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/prepare-stack-trace.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/errors.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/create-cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js'
  ]
}
```

Anything I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: you installed gatsby 1 or 2?

Comment: I installed gatsby-cli@2.8.21

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're having the problem but you can install the missing module to your project with:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-code-frame
```